# Key file permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 644

Tags: php, laravel, passport-js

O erro retornado é o seguinte: Key file permissions are not correct, should be 600 or 660 instead of 644
alguem pode me ajudar resolver este erro ? sei que tenho que mudar para 600 ou 644 , mas nao sei como

Comment: Você está usando um sistema unix/linux?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa mudar para **600**, não 644. Apenas o usuário que roda o servidor web deve ter acesso à essas chaves.

Comece mudando a propriedade das chaves para o usuário que executa seu servidor. Vá na pasta onde está a raiz da sua aplicação e execute o seguinte:

```
$ chown <usuario_do_servidor_web> storage/oauth-private.key storage/oauth-public.key
```

Se você usa Apache e não alterou as configurações no Ubuntu ou variantes, o usuário normalmente é **www-data**, mas verifique as suas configurações para informar o usuário correto.

Comment: C:\www\laravel\aapiVeiculos>chown <usuario_do_servidor_web> storage/oauth-private.key storage/oauth-public.key
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Ah, você usa Windows. Nesse caso não sei como posso te ajudar.